Can I detect usage of Chrome Google Lens on website?
Google Chrome has a Google Lens option that allows to take a screenshot and then copy the text. My website has multiple ways setups to discourage users to take screenshots like showing an alert when pressing the screenshot button:
            window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
                if (e.keyCode === 44) { // Detect Print Screen

This does not work when using the Google Lens function of Chrome. Is there a way to detect the use of Chrome Google Lens through JavaScript or any other way? I understand its not possible to make screenshots impossible, but I want to discourage the user from taking screenshots. Having an inbuilt Chrome function that lets users bypass it is unfortunate.
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function() {


Does not work

you correctly know that it's impossible to prevent google lens entirely... anyway in terms of warning the user you may for example listen for the blur event on window that will popup an alert when the page has lost focus (it will trigger on google lens without preventing it and also when changing tab). Or you may try with contextmenu event on the whole document to prevent the right click... but yet it won't avoid using Google Lens from the Chrome Menu button.

@DiegoD I surely won't revisit any page, that alerts a warning everytime I click away from that page ...

No, luckily there is no way to detect or prevent anything that's going on outside of your page with javascript. Think about the security implications that would cause if a  JS script on a random page could do such things ...

@derpirscher I wouldn't neither.. but let's put it this way.. it was a quick suggestion leading to an approach. A window event handler listening for blur may have conditions trying to narrow down the scenario away from unwanted ones (but I can't say how specifically) .. and the other approach was more straightforward.. but yet it's not clear the exact scenario so maybe it was still valuable in general. Anyway of course there's no exact solution here. Also trying to blur contents won't work because google lens will unblur them
